# mvn package for my Java AWS Lambda function cannot resolve Lambdalogger class during compilation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

When I run `mvn package`, Maven returns an error:

```
[ERROR]   /C:/git/java-project/src/main/java/example/Hello.java:[4,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Lambdalogger
[ERROR]   location: package com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime
[ERROR]   /C:/git/java-project/src/main/java/example/Hello.java:[8,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Lambdalogger
[ERROR]   location: class example.Hello
```

This is my Java code for the AWS Lambda function (in `Hello.java`)

```
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Lambdalogger;

public class Hello {
public String myHandler(int myCount, Context context) {
    Lambdalogger logger = context.getLogger();
    logger.log("received : " + myCount);
    return String.valueOf(myCount);
}
};
```

So it seems Lambdalogger class cannot be resolved, but why? But I have the following dependency listed in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: are you use the shade plugin to capture all the dependencies into the jar?

Comment: Yes I use the shade plugin, and have it entered in the pom.xml file.

Comment: is the issue resolved yet? if not, please share the project github, i can take a look

Comment: This has been resolved. It was the LambdaLogger reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've imported with the wrong class name `Lambdalogger`. The correct class name is `LambdaLogger` with a capital L.

Comment: Have you modified "aws-lambda-java-core" package? `src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/Context/App.java` is not part of the mentioned package. So, it's highly unlikely you would get this error w/o modifying the package

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have not modified the aws-lambda-java-core package. My only reference to it is in the pom.xml file, `<dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>` . Also, I have run `mvn clean` before the `mvn package` to ensure I have no stale references. Is this what you mean?